# <arrayname>.Contains method always returns false

Tags: c#, arrays, class

The class to randomly generate playing cards:

```
class Card
{
    private string face;
    private string suit;

    //Constructor
    public Card()
    {
        string[] faceArray = {"Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"
        , "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        string[] suitArray = { "Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds" };

        Random rand = new Random();
        face = faceArray[rand.Next(0, 13)];
        Thread.Sleep(150);
        Random dand = new Random();
        suit = suitArray[dand.Next(0, 4)];
    }
    //Method face of suit
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return face + " of " + suit;
    }
}
```

This works properly I think, but here's where the trouble is:

```
class DeckOfCards
{
    private Card[] deck = new Card[52];

    //constructor fills deck with unique cards
    public DeckOfCards()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {
            Card tempCard = new Card();
            if (deck.Contains(tempCard))
                 i--; 
            else               
                 deck[i] = tempCard; 
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I have:

```
if (deck.Contains(tempCard))
                     i--;
```

The deck still produces repeats. Am I using the array method incorrectly?

Comment: You create a new temporary card and then check if the deck contains it, why would that return true?

Comment: the temporary card has a face and a suit value. My intention is to check if the array contains a card with the same properties. Im not sure I used it properly

Comment: Then you should check the values of the properties, not the objects. Do not use the contains method.

Comment: Im not sure how to do that. How would I compare the values of the objects?

Comment: Sorry, Im not too sure what you mean by 'contains function'. <arrayname>.Contains is already in visual studios' c#

Comment: OT instead of letting the Card randomize itself an try to get a full deck, you can also assign the deck in order and then shuffle it

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to check the Card object.
Therefore it will use the .Equals() method of that class.

Please override the Equals() method of Card class with your business logic.
Then it will work as you expect.

```
class Card
{
    private string face;
    private string suit;

    //
    // your other methods
    //

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var item = obj as Card;

        if (item == null)
        {
           return false;
        }

        return this.face.Equals(item.face) && this.suit.Equals(item.suit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would i be replacing .Contains() with .Equals() then?

Comment: No.
Add the Equals() method in the Card class.
Don't change the other codes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not have a `Contains`method on an array but you have it on a `List` for example. So your actual code should not compile. However instead of using a List we can keep the array and **use a method extension**. A method extension is a cool way to extend classes with methods that they were not defined with but that could be usefull in a particular context. So let's add a Contains method on a deck of cards.

We can do it the following way:

```
public static class CardFinder
    {
        public static bool Contains(this Card[] deck, Card card)
        {
            if (deck == null)
                return false;

            Card c = Array.Find(deck, c => c != null && c.face.Equals(card.face) && c.suit.Equals(card.suit));

            return c != null;
        }
    }
```

The syntax is particular here. First **the class should be static** and we can notice the **presence of the keyword this** before the first parameter which is of type `Card[]`. That's the way to tell the framework that we want to extend the Card[] type with the new method that we are currently defining called Contains.

In the method we use `Array.Find` method, we is defined as following in the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.find?view=netframework-4.8)

> Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns the first occurrence within the entire Array.

We also need to make the fields of the Card accessible for the sake of the comparison, so let's change their visibility and let's define **getters** and **setters** for them. The beginning of the Card class will look like the following (the rest in unchanged)

```
public class Card
{
     public string face { get; set; }
     public string suit { get; set; }

     // Rest of code here ...
}
```

The DeckOfCards class does not need to change as well, but for the sake of printing commodity I have overriden its ToString method like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   foreach (var card in deck)
      builder.Append(card.ToString() + "\n");
   return builder.ToString();
}
```

No we can test and see that it is working as expected (It takes a little bit of time to compute, so there are certainly opportunities for optimisations here, but I hope this helps):

[image]

Comment: Linq will support array to use Contains() method.